# Measuring seasonality effect

Tags: time-series, python, seasonality

I am working on a research problem related to time series analysis. Now, I have STL decomposition and FB Prophet to decompose my data into trend, seasonality and residual. I struggle with measuring the strength of my seasonality component. In the book Forecasting: Principles and Practice, there is a formula which is the ratio of var(residual) to var(residual + seasonality) (takes 0 if negative). Yet, it's very difficult to build an intuition behind it, on repeated trials it shows that daily seasonality is pretty much zero (though my algorithms suggest that there is one.) I would appreciate any hints and suggestions as to measuring the strength of seasonality. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps this [related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/251009) is relevant. You may also search for other [tag:seasonality] related questions.

Comment: thank you! though the question is about how to measure the strength of seasonality.

Answer (score 2):

> on repeated trials it shows that daily seasonality is pretty much zero (though my algorithms suggest that there is one.)

I am not sure about Prophet, but [STL will fit a seasonal component whether or not one is present](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/220303/1352). This may account for your observation.

I personally would fit seasonal and non-seasonal models to your data and assess forecast accuracy on a holdout sample for both models. Then you can quantify by how much including seasonality reduces your MSE. (And whether it does so at all.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you dealing with simple or complex seasonality in your data? For example, monthly data may show monthly seasonality whereas hourly data may show daily and weekly seasonality.

I think your decomposition would need to reflect whether the seasonality in your data is simple or complex. Simple seasonality would produce a single seasonal component when decomposing the time series into its component parts, whereas multiple seasonality would produce multiple seasonal components.  For an example of the latter, see https://otexts.com/fpp2/complexseasonality.html.

One way to retrieve the long term trend and seasonal component(s) in your time series would be using a GAM model.  For this type of model, you can report an adjusted R squared and keep track of improvements in adjusted R squared associated with introducing additional systematic components to the model.

Comment: thank you for your response! I am dealing with complex seasonality and am using a gam model.
in the book that you've referenced, there is a formula called seasonality strength (https://otexts.com/fpp2/seasonal-strength.html), do you happen to know if there are alternative ways to measure this 'strength'? thank you!

Comment: That's what I thought - you would have to worry about complex seasonality. Rob Hyndman shows some detailed R code for cases where simple seasonality would be at play here: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscharacteristics/. But the code won't work for complex seasonality. Maybe you could reach out to Rob and ask him if he has worked on extending that approach to complex seasonality? I am not familiar with this area so I can't really help.